# Почему не приходит письмо с формы?

Tags: wordpress

В форме контактов сообщение удачно отправляется, на почту приходит с той самой почты, оповещение, что сообщение отправлено и тех.поддержка скоро ответит. Но на саму почту куда должен запрос от клиента прийти сообщение не приходит. В чём может быть проблема?

[image: Скриншот]

Используется самописанный скрипт. Не contactform и прочие.

Код index.php:

```
add_filter('placed_captcha', 'placed_captcha_contact');
function placed_captcha_contact($placed){
    $placed['contactform'] = __('Contact form','pn');
    return $placed;
}

function get_contact_form_filelds($place='shortcode'){
    $ui = wp_get_current_user();

    $items = array();
    $items['name'] = array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'title' => __('Your name', 'pn'),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'req' => 1,
        'value' => pn_strip_input(is_isset($ui,'first_name')),
        'type' => 'input',
        'not_auto' => 0,
        'classes' => 'notclear',
    );
    $items['email'] = array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'title' => __('Your e-mail', 'pn'),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'req' => 1,
        'value' => is_email(is_isset($ui,'user_email')),
        'type' => 'input',
        'not_auto' => 0,
        'classes' => 'notclear',
    );  
    $items['exchange_id'] = array(
        'name' => 'exchange_id',
        'title' => __('Exchange ID', 'pn'),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'req' => 0,
        'value' => '', 
        'type' => 'input',
        'not_auto' => 0,
    );  
    $items['text'] = array(
        'name' => 'text',
        'title' => __('Message', 'pn'),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'req' => 1,
        'value' => '',
        'type' => 'text',
        'not_auto' => 0,
    );  
    $items = apply_filters('get_form_filelds', $items, 'contactform', $ui, $place);
    $items = apply_filters('contact_form_filelds',$items, $ui, $place);

    return $items;
}

global $premiumbox;
$premiumbox->auto_include($path.'/shortcode');
```

и contactform.php

```
edButtons[edButtons.length] = 
new edButton('premium_contact', '<?php _e('Contact form','pn'); ?>','[contact_form]');
<?php   
}

add_filter('list_admin_notify','list_admin_notify_contactform');
function list_admin_notify_contactform($places_admin){
    $places_admin['contactform'] = __('Contact form','pn');
    return $places_admin;
}

add_filter('list_user_notify','list_user_notify_contactform');
function list_user_notify_contactform($places_admin){
    $places_admin['contactform_auto'] = __('Auto-responder (contact form)','pn');
    return $places_admin;
}

add_filter('list_notify_tags_contactform','def_mailtemp_tags_contactform');
add_filter('list_notify_tags_contactform_auto','def_mailtemp_tags_contactform');
function def_mailtemp_tags_contactform($tags){

    $tags['name'] = __('Your name','pn');
    $tags['exchange_id'] = __('Exchange ID','pn');
    $tags['text'] = __('Text','pn');
    $tags['email'] = __('Your e-mail','pn');
    $tags['link'] = __('Reply link','pn');
    $tags['ip'] = __('IP address','pn');

    return $tags;
}

function pn_contact_form_shortcode($atts) {

    $temp = '';

    $ui = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = intval($ui->ID); 

    $items = get_contact_form_filelds();
    $html = prepare_form_fileds($items, 'contact_form_line', 'cf');

    $array = array(
        '[form]' => '<form method="post" class="ajax_post_form" action="'. get_ajax_link('contactform') .'">',
        '[/form]' => '</form>',
        '[result]' => '<div class="resultgo"></div>',
        '[html]' => $html,
        '[submit]' => '<input type="submit" formtarget="_top" name="submit" class="cf_submit" value="'. __('Send a message', 'pn') .'" />',
    );  

    $temp = '
    <div class="cf_div_wrap">
    [form]

        <div class="cf_div_title">
            <div class="cf_div_title_ins">
                '. __('Contact form','pn') .'
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cf_div">
            <div class="cf_div_ins">

                [html]

                <div class="cf_line has_submit">
                    [submit]
                </div>

                [result]

            </div>
        </div>

    [/form]
    </div>
    ';

    $temp = apply_filters('contact_form_temp',$temp);
    $temp = get_replace_arrays($array, $temp);

    return $temp;
}
add_shortcode('contact_form', 'pn_contact_form_shortcode');

add_action('myaction_site_contactform', 'def_myaction_ajax_contactform');
function def_myaction_ajax_contactform(){
global $or_site_url, $premiumbox;   

    only_post();

    $log = array();
    $log['response'] = '';
    $log['status'] = '';
    $log['status_code'] = 0;
    $log['status_text'] = '';
    $log['errors'] = array();

    $premiumbox->up_mode();

    $ui = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = intval($ui->ID); 

    $log = apply_filters('before_ajax_form_field', $log, 'contactform');
    $log = apply_filters('before_ajax_contactform', $log);

    $parallel_error_output = get_parallel_error_output();

    $name = pn_maxf_mb(pn_strip_input(is_param_post('name')), 150);
    $email = is_email(is_param_post('email'));
    $exchange_id = pn_maxf_mb(pn_strip_input(is_param_post('exchange_id')), 300);
    $text = pn_maxf_mb(pn_strip_input(is_param_post('text')), 2000);

    $field_errors = array();

    if(mb_strlen($name) < 2){
        $field_errors[] = __('Error! You must enter your name','pn');   
    }
    if(count($field_errors) == 0 or $parallel_error_output == 1){
        if(!$email){
            $field_errors[] = __('Error! You must enter your e-mail','pn');
        }   
    }
    if(count($field_errors) == 0 or $parallel_error_output == 1){
        if(mb_strlen($text) < 3){
            $field_errors[] = __('Error! You must enter a message','pn');
        }
    }   

    if(count($field_errors) == 0){

        $notify_tags = array();
        $notify_tags['[sitename]'] = pn_strip_input(get_bloginfo('sitename'));
        $notify_tags['[name]'] = $name;
        $notify_tags['[user]'] = $name;
        $notify_tags['[email]'] = $email;
        $notify_tags['[text]'] = $text;
        $notify_tags['[ip]'] = pn_real_ip();
        $notify_tags['[exchange_id]'] = $exchange_id;
        $notify_tags['[idz]'] = $exchange_id;
        $notify_tags['[link]'] = '<a href="mailto:'. $email .'?subject=[subject]">'. __('Reply','pn') .'</a>';
        $notify_tags = apply_filters('notify_tags_contactform', $notify_tags, $ui);     

        $user_send_data = array();
        $result_mail = apply_filters('premium_send_message', 0, 'contactform', $notify_tags, $user_send_data); 

        $notify_tags = apply_filters('notify_tags_contactform_auto', $notify_tags, $ui);

        $user_send_data = array(
            'user_email' => $email,
            'user_phone' => is_isset($ui, 'user_phone'),
        );  
        $result_mail = apply_filters('premium_send_message', 0, 'contactform_auto', $notify_tags, $user_send_data);

        $log['status'] = 'success_clear';
        $log['status_text'] = apply_filters('ajax_contactform_success_message',__('Your message has been successfully sent','pn'));     

    } else {

        $log['status'] = 'error';
        $log['status_code'] = 1;
        $log['status_text'] = join("<br />", $field_errors);

    }

    echo json_encode($log);
    exit;
}
```

И что тут не верно указано? Не могу найти куда письмо отправляется. Вижу только где указывается почта клиента.

Comment: Проверяйте `$result_mail` (2 раза). Проверяйте, как именно отправляется почта (где код фильтра `premium_send_message`?). Почему перед первой отправкой у вас `$user_send_data` - пустой массив? Причина может быть в этом. А также: в использовании `mail()` вместо `wp_mail()`, неправильных настроек почтового сервера, отсутствия SPF, DKIM, DMARC.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать.